# Manga about a guy who was reborn as some noble's daughter

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The guy was a playboy, who used women as he wanted. He died and was reborn as some noble's first daughter. The daughter was useless(?) and tried(?) to kill herself with poison. MC started to fight with second daughter and her mother for power in family. I think MC died at 25-30 years old, and the noble's daughter's body he was reborn into was like 14-17 but it was long ago and I can't remember it well. I remember one thing though After he was reborn he was bold as a woman and still disrespects them and treats them as playthings even the mother of his new body. I read like 3 years ago, maybe little less on some website that don't exist anymore.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @Valorum well it was a looong time ago, i don't know how my brain reminded me about it right now :D

Comment: @SirJaner Sure, but was "a long time ago" 50 years or 10? And were you reading it as it was being published, or was it already completed?

Comment: @IMSoP it was like 3 years ago, well in actual time it's not much but in these 3 years i read hundreds other mangas and novels. About amount i think it was just starting, but cant be sure. The sites i was jumping through a lot of them.

Comment: *Middle-Aged Man's Noble Daughter Reincarnation* is only a superficial resemblance, as the protagonist is actually very nice (despite realizing he's supposed to be playing the villainess) although his older mannerisms come off as haughty.

Comment: @SirJaner Right, but when and where did you read are on the checklists Valorum linked through. Did you have physical copies? Official e-books? Fan translations? Remember that all the things that are obvious to you are complete unknowns to the people trying to answer your question.

Comment: Sort of reminds me of Youjo Senki, though looking it up on the series' wiki it looks like Tanya earns her noble title in that series through her military deeds, rather than being born to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could it be the Korean manhwa *Circle Zero's Otherworldy Hero Business*, which dates from 2017-2018?

According to Anime Planet, it has the following description:

> An egocentric man who's led a successful life as the CEO of a company
> in modern society is murdered and reborn as a beautiful lady named
> Paril from a noble family in a fantasy world. Once he wakes up, (now
> in the body of Paril,) he finds out that he's now in the body of an
> "inferior being" and that all his wealth, achievements and successful
> life have vanished. Therefore, he decides to rebuild everything from
> scratch and make it to the "top of the pyramid" in this parallel
> world.

Quickly glancing through online sources indicates that there's apparently an attempted suicide by poison by the host body,  the main character is in the body of the daughter of the first wife of a noble, and there's a second wife who seems to be an antagonist with a daughter of her own.

Comment: Yes thank you this is it :D